# Load stickers from the Server and show in iMessage app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, imessage-extension, ios-stickers

I am starting work on a Sticker pack application. I created a new project and selected the iMessage application.

My requirements are:

1. Download the stickers from the Server and show them in CollectionView.
2. The user should tap on the Sticker and add it to the chat thread.

After googling many solutions I see that for sending stickers, it is necessary to set path of the image and localized description. But when we fetch the images from server we only have image server path.

How i send the sticker via local path?

Answer (score 0):

You can´t do that. Stickers have to be in the App Bundle. The bundle can´t be changed from within the App.